# Opencv integration in Android studio for app development

Tags: opencv, android-studio

How to integrate opencv in Android Studio? I am facing problem in importing and installing opencv library in android studio

Comment: You can learn about open cv from some books which you can get from http://www.filtrlink.com and search for opencv in the search box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install openCV in Android Studio**
Simple Steps:-**(Indirect Method)**

1. Download/Install(Extract)  OpenCV for Android  (you might already have it)
   Download :-[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.11/OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk.zip/download)
   Documentation :- [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)
   I used 2.4.11 version.
2. Open you Android Project on Android Studio.
   Import Module
   (**Files >> New >> Import Module**)
   Browse the path to the samples Folder inside OpenCV for Android Folder and Select any one of the Samples
   **eg :-OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\samples\15-puzzle** 
   **While importing keep everything checked.**
   **This will automatically add OpenCV Libraries Module to your project.**
   Now you can delete the 15-puzzle module (this is optional).
3. In the gradle file of your app add dependency :-
   **compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')**
    `dependencies { compile project(':openCVLibrary2411') }`
4. Now you can Import openCV classes in your project

   eg:-

`import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;`
`import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;`
`import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;`